# Angularjs $q.all

Tags: angularjs, promise, q

I have implemented the $q.all in angularjs, but I can not make the code work. Here is my code :

```
UploadService.uploadQuestion = function(questions){

        var promises = [];

        for(var i = 0 ; i < questions.length ; i++){

            var deffered  = $q.defer();
            var question  = questions[i]; 

            $http({

                url   : 'upload/question',
                method: 'POST',
                data  : question
            }).
            success(function(data){
                deffered.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function(error){
                deffered.reject();
            });

            promises.push(deffered.promise);
        }

        return $q.all(promises);
    }
```

And here is my controller which call the services:

```
uploadService.uploadQuestion(questions).then(function(datas){

   //the datas can not be retrieved although the server has responded    
}, 
function(errors){ 
   //errors can not be retrieved also

})
```

I think there is some problem setting up $q.all in my service.

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing?  Does it call into your `then(datas)`?  Try to just `push` this: `promises.push(deffered);`

Comment: I have tried and both method works on my case. But I will make @Llan Frumer as the correct answer. Really thank you both of you.

Comment: Why are you promise-izing an existing promise?  $http already returns a promise.  Use of  $q.defer is superfluous.

Comment: It is `deferred` not `deffered` :)

Answer (score 225, accepted):

In javascript there are no **`block-level scopes`** only **`function-level scopes`**:

Read this article about [javaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

### See how I debugged your code:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.count = i;

console.log(deferred.count); // 0,1,2,3,4,5 --< all deferred objects

// some code

.success(function(data){
   console.log(deferred.count); // 5,5,5,5,5,5 --< only the last deferred object
   deferred.resolve(data);
})
```

- When you write `var deferred= $q.defer();` inside a for loop it's **hoisted** to the top of the function, it means that javascript declares this variable on the function scope outside of the `for loop`.
- With each loop, the last *deferred* is overriding the previous one, there is no block-level scope to save a reference to that object.
- When asynchronous callbacks (success / error) are invoked, they reference only the last **deferred object** and only it gets resolved, so **$q.all is never resolved** because it still waits for other deferred objects.
- What you need is to create an anonymous function for each item you iterate.
- Since functions do have scopes, the reference to the deferred objects are preserved in a **`closure scope`** even after functions are executed.
- As #dfsq commented: There is no need to manually construct a new deferred object since $http itself returns a promise.

  ---

#### Solution with `angular.forEach`:

Here is a demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NGMp4ycmaCqVOmgohN53?p=preview

```
UploadService.uploadQuestion = function(questions){

    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach(questions , function(question) {

        var promise = $http({
            url   : 'upload/question',
            method: 'POST',
            data  : question
        });

        promises.push(promise);

    });

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

#### My favorite way is to use `Array#map`:

Here is a demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KYeTWUyxJR4mlU77svw9?p=preview

```
UploadService.uploadQuestion = function(questions){

    var promises = questions.map(function(question) {

        return $http({
            url   : 'upload/question',
            method: 'POST',
            data  : question
        });

    });

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. One addition: no need to construct new deferred since $http itself returns promise. So it can be shorter: http://plnkr.co/edit/V3gh7Roez8WWl4NKKrqM?p=preview

Comment: "When you write var deferred= $q.defer(); inside a for loop it's hoisted to the top of the function.". I dont understand this part, can you explain the reason behind it ?

Comment: I know, I would do the same actually.

Comment: Love the use of `map` to build an array of promises. Very simple and concise.

Comment: Legendary answer! Thanks to your explanation, I can see that since you are pushing the promise returned by the $http call directly into your array of promises, you no longer need a separate scope to save the reference to the unnecessary, intermediary deferred. This means the OP could technically go back to using a simple for loop, although I must admit that using "map"  seems to be the most elegant way to create an array of promises in this case.

Comment: Great answer. Let's say this wasn't a POST but a GET method. How do you iterate over the promises to get data belonging to each promise?

Comment: It should be noted that the declaration is hoisted, but the assignment stays where it is.  Also, there is now block-level scoping with the 'let' statement. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 37):

$http is a promise too, you can make it simpler:

```
return $q.all(tasks.map(function(d){
        return $http.post('upload/tasks',d).then(someProcessCallback, onErrorCallback);
    }));
```

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer is just an agglomeration of anti-patterns.

Comment: I think you can leave the `.then()` clause out as the OP wants to do all that in his controller, but the principle is totally correct.

Comment: of course you can omit the then clause, i added it in case you want to log all the HTTP requests, i always add them and use a global onError callback, to handle all server exceptions.

Comment: @Zerkotin you can `throw` from a `.then` in order to both handle it later _and_ expose it to `$exceptionHandler`, which should save you that trouble and a global.

Comment: Nice. This is essentially the same approach as the accepted answer's last solution/example.

Comment: Would `.then` fire for every promise of `e`? How would I get `someCallback` to fire just when all of the promises return? Add it to `$q.all(promises).then(someCallBack)`?

Answer (score 12):

The issue seems to be that you are adding the `deffered.promise` when `deffered` is itself the promise you should be adding:

Try changing to `promises.push(deffered);` so you don't add the unwrapped promise to the array.

```
 UploadService.uploadQuestion = function(questions){

            var promises = [];

            for(var i = 0 ; i < questions.length ; i++){

                var deffered  = $q.defer();
                var question  = questions[i]; 

                $http({

                    url   : 'upload/question',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data  : question
                }).
                success(function(data){
                    deffered.resolve(data);
                }).
                error(function(error){
                    deffered.reject();
                });

                promises.push(deffered);
            }

            return $q.all(promises);
        }
```

Comment: This only returns an array of deffered objects, I checked it.

Comment: I don't know what he says, only what the console says, You can see it's not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/J1ErNncNsclf3aU86D7Z?p=preview

Comment: Also the documentation says clearly that `$q.all` gets promises not deferred objects. The real problem of the OP is with scoping and because that only the last deferred is getting resolved

Comment: Ilan, thanks for disentangling `defer` objects and `promises`.  You fixed my `all()` issue as well.

Comment: the problem was resolved in 2 answers, the problem is scoping or variable hoisting, whatever you want to call it.