# Multiple dependent controllers/directives on a single page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

I want to display something like this in a single page.  The complication is that this data comes from 4 different sources.

```
City One
    Property One
    Property Two
    Property Three A
    Property Three B
    Property Three C

City Two
    Property One
    Property Two
    Property Three A
    Property Three B
    Property Three C

City Three
    Property One
    Property Two
    Property Three A
    Property Three B
    Property Three C
```

- City - comes from JSON A, which returns a simple array of n objects containing name and id.
- Property One comes from JSON B (using City.id as a parameter in the URL), returning one set of objects specific to City.id.
- Property Two comes from JSON C (using City.id as a parameter in the URL), returning one set of objects specific to City.id.
- Property Three A/B/C comes from JSON D (using an key field returned in Property Two), returning one set of objects specific to a particular property key specified in Property Two.

Is this even doable?  I'm aware that this requires 3n+1 semi-synchronous JSON calls.  At this point I don't know if I should be looking for help on controllers or directives or some kind of crazy routing or what.

I'm a total noob at Angular (I come from an ASP.NET MVC background) and I can't wrap my ahead around this.  I've been trying to follow John Papa's Style Guide, so there isn't a $scope to be found anywhere in my code, which is severely limiting my understanding of some pages I've looked up to solve this.

Comment: Seems like you wanted to wait till all three request complete..If you want that you could use `$q.all` which will accept promise array & wait till they gets completed..

Comment: So you're saying I should do all this in one controller/service, rather than 4 nested controllers?

Comment: Yes I would definitely do this in one controller rather than 4 nested controllers. I've found it very messy when trying to nest a large number of controllers.

Comment: A good example of $q.all can be found here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all)