# How can I run a javascript function only after a $http request has been made in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm working on an Angular.js app which makes some calls to the GitHub API. First, a call is made to retrieve all the repos for a user. Then for each repo, a call is made to retrieve the README. I have a javascript function which I would like to be run only after all the README API calls are completed.

Here is my controller:

```
readmeSearch.controller('ReadMeSearchController', ['RepoSearch', 'ReadMeSearch', function(RepoSearch, ReadMeSearch) {

  var self = this;
  self.gitRepoNames = [];
  self.readMes = [];
  self.noReadMes = [];

  self.doSearch = function() {
    RepoSearch.query(self.username)
      .then(function(repoResponse) {
        addRepoNames(repoResponse);
        for(var i = 0; i< self.gitRepoNames.length; i++) {
          (function(i) {
            ReadMeSearch.query(self.username, self.gitRepoNames[i])
              .then(function(readMeResponse) {
                addToReposWithReadMes(readMeResponse, i);
              }).catch(function(e){
                addToReposWithoutReadMes(repoResponse, i);
              });
          })(i);
        };
      });
  };

  addRepoNames = function(response) {
    self.searchResult = response.data;
    for(var i = 0; i < self.searchResult.length; i++) {
      var name = self.searchResult[i]['name']
      self.gitRepoNames.push(name);
    };
  };

  addToReposWithReadMes = function(response, i) {
    self.readMes.push(
      {
        name: self.gitRepoNames[i],
        size: parseInt(response.data["size"]),
        url: response.data["html_url"]
      }
    );
  };

  addToReposWithoutReadMes = function(response, i) {
    self.noReadMes.push(
      {
        name: self.gitRepoNames[i]
      }
    );
  };

  percentageOfReposWithReadMes = function() {
    var percentage;
    percentage = (self.noReadMes.length / self.gitRepoNames.length) * 100
    self.readMePercentage = percentage.toFixed(1);
  };

}]);
```

The README API calls using the ReadMeSearch factory populate two arrays, one for repos with READMEs and one for repos without READMEs. I would like to run the function `percentageOfReposWithReadMes` only after the `ReadMeSearch.query` has been completed for all the repos in `self.gitRepoNames`.

I've tried using `.then` after the `RepoSearch.query` but this doesn't seem to work. I think I'm a bit muddled in my understanding of Angular promises and the `.then` function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, everything after `RepoSearch.query(self.username)` doesn't work? Cause you have a `.then` there. EDIT: oh nevermind, I understand what you meant now, looking into it

Comment: It all works fine I'm just trying to run the function `percentageOfReposWithReadMes` but this can only be run after the both the `self.noReadMes` and `self.gitRepoNames` have been populated i.e after the all the ReadMeSeach queries in the for loop have been completed. @klskl. EDIT: ah just read your edit @klskl, sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: @dbatten, you can either count number of requests finished and to check if **all** of the are proceeded or to use `$q.all` passing all promises to it and using `.then()` funciton as a result of when all promises **are resolved**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Return** your promises and **chain** from those promises

```
 self.doSearch = function() {
    var namesPromise = 
        RepoSearch.query(self.username)
            .then(function(repoResponse) {
                 addRepoNames(repoResponse);
                 //return promises for chaining
                 return lookupNamesPromises(repoResponse);
            }) .catch (function (error) {
                 //log error
            });
    //chain from promise
    namesPromise.then (function(promises) {
        $q.all(promises).finally( function() {
            percentageOfReposWithReadMes();
        })
    });
    //return promise for chaining elsewhere
    return namesPromise;
  };
```

Lookup function returns an array of promise.

```
  self.lookupNamesPromises = function (repoResponse) {
    var namesPromises = [];
    for(var i = 0; i< self.gitRepoNames.length; i++) {
          //begin IIFE closure
          (function(i) {
              var p = (ReadMeSearch.query(self.username, self.gitRepoNames[i])
                       .then(function(readMeResponse) {
                           addToReposWithReadMes(readMeResponse, i);
                           return readMeResponse;
                       }).catch(function(e){
                           addToReposWithoutReadMes(e, i);
                           return e;
                       })
              );
              namesPromises.push(p);
          })(i);
          //end IIFE closure
    }
           //return promises for chaining
    return namesPromises;
  };
```

By chaining your promises, subsequent functions will wait for previous functions to complete. The rule of thumb in functional programming is **always return something**.

Comment: hi @georgeawg many thanks for your response. that seems to be working all fine, I think I was a bit muddled in my understanding of promises and $q but your answer has really cleared it up. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `$q.all`, this will reslove an array of promises, and `.then` after all these are done, you would run your function.

I'm having trouble trying this myself, would be easier if you had a plunkr or something.

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all) thread that explains this pretty good, maybe you can find your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create two defers and resolve then when the loop finish. With $q.all you can wait for till both refers finish and call the `percentageOfReposWithReadMes` function.

```
  readmeSearch.controller('ReadMeSearchController', ['RepoSearch', 'ReadMeSearch', '$q', function(RepoSearch, ReadMeSearch, $q) {

  var self = this;
  var gitRepoNameDefer;
  var noReadMesDefer;
  self.gitRepoNames = [];
  self.readMes = [];
  self.noReadMes = [];


  self.doSearch = function() {
    RepoSearch.query(self.username)
      .then(function(repoResponse) {
        gitRepoNameDefer = $q.defer();
        noReadMesDefer = $q.defer();
        addRepoNames(repoResponse);
        for(var i = 0; i< self.gitRepoNames.length; i++) {
          (function(i) {
            ReadMeSearch.query(self.username, self.gitRepoNames[i])
              .then(function(readMeResponse) {
                addToReposWithReadMes(readMeResponse, i);
              }).catch(function(e){
                addToReposWithoutReadMes(repoResponse, i);
              }).finally(function () {
                 finishDefers(i, self.gitRepoNames.length - 1);
              });
          })(i);
        }
        $q.all([gitRepoNameDefer, noReadMesDefer ]).then(fucntion () {
          percentageOfReposWithReadMes();
        });
      });
  };

  addRepoNames = function(response) {
    self.searchResult = response.data;
    for(var i = 0; i < self.searchResult.length; i++) {
      var name = self.searchResult[i]['name']
      self.gitRepoNames.push(name);

    };
  };

  addToReposWithReadMes = function(response, i) {
    self.readMes.push(
      {
        name: self.gitRepoNames[i],
        size: parseInt(response.data["size"]),
        url: response.data["html_url"]
      }
    );

  };

  addToReposWithoutReadMes = function(response, i) {
    self.noReadMes.push(
      {
        name: self.gitRepoNames[i]
      }
    );

  };

 function finishDefers (index, limit) {
   if (index === limit) {
      gitRepoNameDefer.resolve(self.readMes);
      noReadMesDefer.resolve(self.noReadMes);
   }
 }

 function percentageOfReposWithReadMes () {
    var percentage;
    percentage = (self.noReadMes.length / self.gitRepoNames.length) * 100
    self.readMePercentage = percentage.toFixed(1);
  };

}]);
```

Comment: hi @raulucco thanks for your response. I get a console error `ReadMeSearch.query(...).then(...).catch(...).always is not a function` when trying to run this

Comment: I'm getting `ReadMeSearch.query(...).then(...).catch(...).done is not a function` now

Comment: ah yes finally is the one, although it still seems to be running before the loop is finished? @raulucco