# How can I call the second sequential promise design pattern method in a loop in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

New to angularjs and trying out the promise pattern for the first time -

I have a service utility inside which I have this method -

```
this.getData= function(url){
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
            success(function(data, status){
                defer.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                defer.reject(status);
            });

        return defer.promise;
    };
```

Now inside my controller, I am calling a method called A()

```
   var A = function () {
    $scope.myobjectArray = [];


    return utility.getData("some url").then(funciton(data)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.myobjectArray.push(data[i].attribute1, new Array());

        }

    }
    ).
    then(function () {

        return getTheSecondAttributeArray();
    }).catch(function (status) {
//display error

    });


};

var getTheSecondAttributeArray = function () {

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.myObjectArray.length; i++) {
        var secondAttributeArray = [];
        var currentType = $scope.myObjectArray[i];
        utility.getData("some url").then(function (response) {
            for (j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
//some response manipulation
                secondAttributeArray.push(response[j].text);
            }
        currentType.secondAttribute = secondAttributeArray;
        }).catch(function () {//catch error, display message
        })

    }
}
```

However, it looks like that the last element of the $scope.myobjectArray (n-1th element) is only getting populated. Also, the secondAttributeArray that this last element contains is a concatenated array of all secondAttributes for all objects of the $scope.myobjectArray.

Cannot figure out what can I change here.

EDIT:

When I tried accessing $scope.myObjectArray[j] inside the 'then' function, it said $scope.myObjectArray[j]  was undefined. --> And so I created a currentType variable and assigned $scope.myObjectArray[j] to it and that was easily accessible inside the 'then' function. Weird!

Also, I see that only the last object of the $scope.myObjectArray gets values and not the rest. The rest of the objects in the array are empty

Any help is appreciated.

```
var myObject = function(firstattribute, secondAttribute){

this.firstattribute = firstattribute;
this.secondAttribute = secondAttribute;
}
```

The explanation here by Beehive ([Angularjs $q.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all)) is something that I am facing. I only get the last loop's data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it - don't wrap $http in a promise it already returns one

Comment: I see, so I should remove the defer portion? Also, its weird that when I do the  $scope.myObjectArray[i].secondAttributeArray = secondAttributeArray; inside the 'then' function, it says $scope.myObjectArray[i] is undefined.

Comment: It's really, really difficult to figure out what you're trying to do without proper indentation. I attempted to edit but had to make too many assumptions to make the parens and brackets line up. Please edit and add proper indents.

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: what's that `returns` in your code?

Comment: Sorry typo. Corrected.

Comment: The most obvious issue is that you're assuming you'll see changes to `secondAttributeArray` from code outside of the `then`. At the very least you should move the `$scope.myObjectArray[i].secondAttributeArray = secondAttributeArray;` to the inside of the `then` block.

Comment: Yup, that's my second question in the description. If I do that, it says $scope.myObjectArray[i] is undefined.

Comment: I also tried passing $scope.myObjectArray[i] in the then function as a renamed variable currentObject and then did the assignment but I see the same issue of last object having all the secondacctributes assigned to it.

Comment: Actually, Now I see that only the last object has a correct value but the rest of the objects do not. Edited the code and description

Comment: Any ideas on why the other objects in the $scope.myObjectArray do not get any values for the secondAttribute but only the last object in the array gets secondAttribute.?

Comment: Interesting is that when I do a console.log(i) inside the 'then' function, I only see value 5 (the max value).

Comment: The explanation here by Beehive (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all) is something that I am facing. I only get the last loop's data.

Comment: Why are you using push(..., new Array())? You might not want this

Comment: I am just assigning it so that in the second method I don't have to , but I can set it to null as well.

Comment: push() receives one or more elements to add to an array. That way, you are adding an empty array every iteration.

Comment: Changed that but that does not really help :(  As added in my previous comment, the explanation here by Beehive (stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all) is something that I am facing. I only get the last loop's data.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is all in function closures. When the get data returns, your currentType is the last one because the for j loop ended already. So what you need to do is move the code starting from `utility.getData` to a separate method passing the parameters of the `currentType` and the `seccondAttributeArray` so the closure will contain them as parameters of the function and not change them as the for j loop progresses.

```
for (i = 0; i < $scope.myObjectArray.length; i++) { 
  var secondAttributeArray = []; 
  var currentType = $scope.myObjectArray[i];
  fillSecondAttributeArray($scope, secondAttributeArray, currentType);
 }
```

Comment: I realized I had a mistake in my code. I have rewritten this line -             currentType.secondAttribute = secondAttributeArray;

Comment: I would actually prefer directly doing something like - $scope.myObjectArray[i],secondAttribute = secondAttirbuteArray  directly instead of using any currentType reference

Comment: You can do whatever you want, just do the `utility.getData` in separate function, you can pass it whatever you want. The issue here is that you reference an object outside the `then` statement that is changing as the loop goes. Did you understand my answer?