# $http request to return all records without pagination in a single request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, angular-promise

There are more than 4000 records. API returns max 1000 records and has pagination. I call for this function (loop), and use "skip" to obtain records at intervals of 1000 records.

I need all records at once, but below code returns only first 1000 records.

```
  var array=[];
  function loop(skip){
     return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: myurl+'&$skip='+skip,
            timeout:5000
      }).success(function(res){
        if(res.d.length>0) 
            {
              Array.prototype.push.apply( array,res.d);
               loop(skip +1000);
            }
        return array;
      }).error(function(response,status,headers,config) {

      });
    }

    getAll = function() {
        return loop(0);
    }
```

I need a single request can obtain the total records.
but only I get the first 1000 records in this part :(

```
    getAll().then(function() {
        console.log("in this part i need the array with my 4000 records")
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all

Comment: so, do you know concrete record count? or you want do request until `res.d.length>0`?

Comment: @Grundy thanks for answering, 4000 records is an example. but "res.d.length> 0" causes the cycle stops when the end will no longer have to get more records. with this condition need to return the total value of records once.

Comment: @d3l33t I have seen the link, but I do not understand how to adjust my code.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the example is interesting but differs somewhat from my logic, I would not know how to adjust.

Comment: @yavg, yep, duplicate was wrong

Comment: i think you just need add return before `loop(skip +1000)`: `return loop(skip +1000);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108437/discussion-between-yavg-and-grundy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a bit sidenote from angular [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#deprecation-notice):

> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to false then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error.

Yet another solution: pass accumulator result as parameter to loop function

```
function loop(skip,result){
  result = result||[];//accumulator for result, init empty array if not pass
  return $http(
    {
          method: 'GET',
          url: myurl+'&$skip='+skip,
          timeout:5000
    }).then(function success(response){
      if(response.data.length > 0){
        Array.prototype.push.apply(result,response.data);
        return loop(skip+1000,result);
      }
      return result;
    },function error(){

    });
}
```

Notice, that main difference from your current code is `return` before calling `loop` function inside success handler.

This work, because if from `then`  function return promise, then next `then` would be applied after returned promise fulfiled.

**[Sample plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XL01AtoBzVcSXoQwicGv?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

Should be possible with some recursive promise chaining. Try this

```
function getAll(page) {
    if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
        page = 0;
    }
    return $http.get(myurl, {$skip: page * 1000}).then(function(res) {
        var data = res.data;
        if (data.length > 0) {
            return getAll(page + 1).then(function(nextData) {
               return data.concat(nextData);
            });
        }
        return data;
    });
}
```

And call it like

```
getAll().then(function(allRecords) {
    console.log(allRecords);
});
```

Here's a hacked together Plunker demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/ey8gdytvuBE6cpuMAtnB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The 
Working sample https://jsfiddle.net/coolbhes/xmqur1bq/  (replaced service with a promise)

Code which would work for you as below :

```
var array = [];

function loop(skip, resolveHandle) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: myurl + '&$skip=' + skip,
        timeout: 5000
    }).then(function successCallback(res) {
        if (res.d.length > 0) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(array, res.d);
            loop(skip + 1000, resolveHandle);
        } else {
            //done with all requests;
            resolveHandle(array);
        }
    }, function errorCallback(rej) {

    });
};

function getAll() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        loop(0, resolve);
    });
}

getAll().then(function(data) {
            console.log("in this part i need the array with my 4000 records", data)
        }
```