# call function after for loop complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-promise

I am try to call function `$scope.getThisFunction($scope.Num)` after completion of for loop, i tried below code but not working. Any suggestion?

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selection.length; i++) {                
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/url/' + $scope.Num + '/' + $scope.selection[i]
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        if(i == $scope.selection.length - 1) {  
           $scope.getThisFunction($scope.Num); //not working
        }
    }, function myError(response) {
        alert("SORRY, SOME TECHNICAL ERROR OCCUR");
    });
}
```

Comment: It is not a very good idea to make HTTP posts in a for-loop. You should rewrite your API to accept several `selections` in one unique call.

Comment: @Pratyush Pranjal
You want the `$scope.getThisFunction($scope.Num)` to be called in the last element of the loop or in the last response of your posts?
If you want it to be called when the last post responds try using promises(`$q.all`)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make separate function and use http request inside that function. Because when for loop looping around it refer the same reference. Even though it create new closure it has the same reference. so it's only taken the last index of for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selection.length; i++) {
    sendReq(i)
};

function sendReq(i) {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/url/' + $scope.Num + '/' + $scope.selection[i]
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        if (i == $scope.selection.length - 1) {
            $scope.getThisFunction($scope.Num); //not working
        }
    }, function myError(response) {
        alert("SORRY, SOME TECHNICAL ERROR OCCUR");
    });
}
```

Comment: who down voted this, if not understanding question please leave it. Great looping concept, working perfectly..!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. In your example you'd have to use

```
if (i === $scope.selection.length)
```

but that will fire multiple times, as the condition should most likely always be true when each promise resolves.

You should use $q.all and pass it an array of promises. $q is an angular service and you simply need to inject it.

**Untested:**

```
var promises = []

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selection.length; i++) {
  promises.push($http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/url/' + $scope.Num + '/' + $scope.selection[i]
  });
}

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
  $scope.getThisFunction($scope.Num);
}, function() {
  alert('Error')
});
```

**Edit:**

I saw you accepted another answer. Let me that it would be easier to just keep your code and replace var by let instead of using a function closure. That would of course only work if you're working in an ES6 environment.

```
for(let i = 0; i < $scope.selection.length; i++)
  ...
```