# how to get callback of all async calls when all get finished in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, deferred

For understanding my situation, I have created [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6pZ6gHIbdg0tI02PAeIS). I need the callback when all async requests get executed.
Note: async functions are called recursively in the loop.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller("Ctrl_List", ["$scope", "$q", "$timeout", function ($scope, $q, $timeout) {
                var promises = [];
                $scope.result='';
                $scope.runAsync = function () {
                    var listOfItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
                    $scope.result='';
                    // Iterating list of items.
                    for (var j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                        promises.push($scope.myAsyncFun(j, promises));
                    }

                    $q.all(promises).then(function () {
                        $scope.result+=' Chain finished!';
                    });
                };

                $scope.myAsyncFun = function (val, promises, deferred) {
                    if (deferred == null) {
                        deferred = $q.defer();
                    }
                    $timeout(function () {
                       $scope.result+=' Item executed: ' + val;

                        if (val % 2 == 0) {
                            for (var k = 0; k < val; k++) {
                                promises.push($scope.myAsyncFun(k, promises, deferred));
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        }

                    }, 1000);

                    return deferred.promise;
                };
            }]);
```

Comment: Take a look at `$q.all`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs $q.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all)

Comment: $q.all gets the list of all promises and wait till all get finished loading. My problem is, some promises are inside recursive loop.